# Changing letters in words in php but not all of the same letter

Tags: php

I want to change the letter a in the word to o, but not all the letter a, in my rule, only the letters a in the words ending with a should be changed to o, but all the letters a are changing to the letter o, kak kok  .  kaka koko is happening.  kak does not end with a, but the letter a in the middle is changing to the letter o.  I need the kak kak state to be in the kaka koko state below.

```
<?php

  $str  = "kak kaka";
 
  $searchVal = array("a");
 
  $replaceVal = array("o");
  
  $res = str_replace($searchVal, $replaceVal, $str);
  print_r($res);
?>
```

I didn't know what to try.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you want "kak kaka" to become "kak koko".  Is that right?  You can't do that with `str_replace`, nor do I think you can do it with a regular expression.  You would need to `explode` the string into words, and go through the words individually, then `implode` them back together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my assumption in the comments was correct, this will do it:

```
<?php
$s = "kak kaak kaka kaaka";
$result = [];
foreach( explode(' ', $s) as $word )
{
    if( substr($word,-1) == 'a' )
        $word = str_replace('a','o',$word);
    $result[] = $word;
}
$result = implode(' ', $result);
echo "$result\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
kak kaak koko kooko
```

Comment: Thanks it worked very accurately.  What can I do if I want to change multiple letters instead of just one letter a like the rule for letter a.
 a -> o
 o -> a
 e -> i
 i -> e
 That is, I want to make not only one letter a but also other letters.  So what can I do?

Comment: ??? You call `str_replace` multiple times.  Be careful that you don't change all the a's to o's, and then change the o's BACK to a's.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added any logic to check for last character validation. For this, you can use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) one line solution to match and *filter* only those words that end with `a` and then use [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace) to replace all `a` with `o`.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

echo preg_replace_callback('/\b[^\s]*a\b/i', fn($matches) => str_replace("a", "o", $matches[0]), 'kak kaka aaak aaa');
```

[**Online Demo**](https://3v4l.org/QnbI2)